# For any real number $x$ there is a real number $y$ such that $y>\dfrac {1} {1+x^{2}}$.

Tags: real-analysis

Can you give a hint for proof? I don't want to use Archimedian property.

Comment: $y=42$, for instance.

Comment: Let $y=42$ and $x=1$. Yet, it is not a proof. Can you explain clearly?

Comment: $0<\frac{1}{1+x^2}\leq 1$ for all $x$, so...

Comment: Why $42$? Well, any number $>1$ would do, but…

Comment: Hint of a proof.  Let y = $\dfrac{1}{1+x^2} $ +1.

Comment: Or you could consider $\frac{1}{1+x^2} + 1$. Gosh! I think this could lead to a remarkable generalisation? Could it be that the real numbers are unbounded? [I see that fleablood has independently come up with the same idea: we must be on to something. $\ddot{\smile}$].

Comment: As per Carmichael hint, I think you wrote the problem down wrong.  Proving what you wrote is trivial.  Just take y = 1+ whatever > whatever.  But I think you are supposed to prove the there is a single y value that is bigger than *all* possible x results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With just the property of ordered field you can prove that
$$
\frac{1}{1+x^2}<42
$$
for all $x$, so a much stronger result. Indeed, $1+x^2>0$, so the inequality is equivalent to
$$
1+x^2>\frac{1}{42}
$$
or
$$
x^2>-\frac{41}{42}
$$
which is true because $x^2\ge0$.

---

There's probably some misunderstanding in the wording of the exercise.

Suppose $f$ is a real function defined (for simplicity) on all real numbers. Consider the following two statements:

> *Statement* ($\mathrm{W}_f$) For all $x$, there exists $y$ such that $y>f(x)$
>
> *Statement* ($\mathrm{S}_f$) There exists $y$ such that, for all $x$, $y>f(x)$

The two statements are very different from each other. Indeed, $(\mathrm{W}_f)$ is *true* for every function $f$: just take $y=f(x)+1$.

On the other hand, statement $(\mathrm{S}_f)$ means that the function $f$ is upper bounded. Since $f(x)=x$ is not upper bounded, statement $(\mathrm{S}_f)$ is *false* for this $f$.

Be careful with the order of quantifiers.

More generally, if $P(x,y)$ is a predicate, the statements

> (W) For all $x$ there exists $y$ such that $P(x,y)$
>
> (S) There exists $y$ such that, for all $x$, $P(x,y)$

are generally not equivalent. *If* statement (S) holds, then also statement (W) holds. But it can happen, for a particular $P$, that statement (W) holds and statement (S) doesn't.

Comment: Okey. So, There is a real number $y$ such that $y>\dfrac {1} {1+x^{2}}$ for any real number $x$.

Comment: @Kahler Yes, any number $y>1$ would do, because $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ has an absolute maximum at $0$ and $f(0)=1$.

Comment: What is difference between my first question and last question?

Comment: First question: For any real number $x$ there is a real number $y$ such that $y>\dfrac {1} {1+x^{2}}$.

Comment: Last question: There is a real number $y$ such that $y>\dfrac {1} {1+x^{2}}$ for any real number $x$.

Comment: indeed, in your answer, we can take $y=\dfrac {1} {1+x^{2}}+1$, cannot we?

Comment: @Kahler Of course! But if you prove the second statement, you don't need to prove the first one. Compare with a different case. Statement (W): “for any $x$ there exists $y$ such that $y>x$”; statement (S): “there exists $y$ such that, for any $x$, $y>x$”. Statement (W) is true, whereas statement (S) is false.

Comment: @Kahler The `first question` is true for any real function $f(x)$ not just $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$. The `last question` isn't, take for example $f(x)=x$.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for editing.

Comment: I still have many question. For statement $S_{f}$, how $f$ is an upper bound but it is not for statement  $W_{f}$?  For statement $S_{f}$, why $f\left( x\right) =x$?

Comment: normally, $f\left( x\right) =\dfrac {1} {1+x^{2}}$, isn't it? What is $f\left( x\right) =x$ means?

Comment: @egreg for the statement $S_{f}$, how did you take $f\left( x\right) =x$?

Comment: @Kahler In the final part, I denote with $f$ a generic function, so I can give different examples. If $f$ is the one in your exercise, then $S_f$ holds; if it is $f(x)=x$, then $S_f$ doesn't hold

Comment: @egreg Sorry, I could not understand. $f$ means that from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, doesn't it? How can you give different examples? You should only take $f(x)=\dfrac {1} {1+x^{2}}$, shouldn't it? I did understand really this. Can you explain clearly proof of $S_{f}$
?

Comment: Edited:  Can you explain clearly the statement of $S_{f}$?

Comment: What is diffirence between $f$ and $f(x)$?

Comment: @Kahler $f$ is the function, $f(x)$ is the value of $f$ at $x$; the former denotes a function, the latter a number.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f (x) = \frac {1}{1+x^2} $

Let $y=1+f (x) > f (x) $

What's to prove?

====

I think maybe you meant prove there exists a *single* value of $y $ that is larger than $f (x) $ for *all* real $x$.

$x^2 \ge 0$

$1+x^2 \ge 1$

So $\frac 1 {1+x^2} \le 1< 5,432,986,198$

So $y=5,432,986,198$ is larger than $f (x) $ for all real $x $.

Comment: is there some significance to that number? Or was that just random keyboard mashing XD

Comment: Utterly no significance whatsoever.  1 is the least upper bound of all values.  If x = 1 then f (x)=1.  So f (x) > = 1.  Any y >1 will work.  There is no least such y, but 1.000000000000000000000001 will do.  I chose 5,432,986,198 to be funny and in the hope the extremity would make the point clear that any y >1 will do.